# Animate and Load in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-load

Hi I have made this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#navigation a:first-child').click(function(){
    $("#space").load("index.html #container").animate({
        top: '-=120'
        }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
});

$('#navigation a:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
    $("#space2").load("index.html #container2").animate({
            bottom: '-=120'
        }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
});         
}); 
</script>
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">home</a>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>

<div id="space" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">

</div>

<div id="space2" style="border: 1px solid #ff0000;">

</div>
```

I want it to animate on click of a link but the first to animate from the left and fade in, the second link to animate from the top and fade in, the third to animate from the right and fade in and the fourth to animate from the bottom and fade in, each I need to control the speed so the first will have a speed of 500, the 2nd a thousand, the third, 1200, the fourth 1500.

If possible i would like them all to load into the same area. I don't know if it can be done

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have everything correct, you just might want to move your animation into the .load callback so the animation doesn't fire until after the element is loaded. Like this:

```
$("#space").load("index.html #myDiv", function(){
    $(this).animate({
        top: '-=120'
            }, 1000, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            });
    });
```

Of course you can control the speed and the animations independent of each other no problem. Just change the '1000' to '500' or '1200' or whatever you want. Also, I am guessing that you will want to position the "space" elements with an absolute position to start (like maybe off the page?), give them a width and height and the animation will be more apparent.

Comment: thanks but i want to load a certain div id or class from that page this is where i got stuck in regards to your above answer as I too thought about that.

Comment: Sorry, I was copying it from a local file, you had it right, just add a space and add the div id like this: "index.html #myDiv", function(){// load complete - start animation}. If you would like to use a class, you can assign a variable to an element with a class and use that instead like this: var myElement = $(".myDiv"); then instead of #myDiv you can go like this: ("#space").load("index.html myElement ", function(){// load complete - start animation}. I have edited my answer accordingly.